# Edit contents title and running header separately

Tags: table-of-contents, xetex, header-footer, small-caps

I'm typesetting a book using XeLaTeX.

In creating the table of contents, I want to have control over:

- The title at the top of the toc
- The running header throughout the toc

I want the contents header to be in all caps, but I want my running header to be in small caps. (The font I am using has small caps in a separate font, and does not have very smart OpenType capabilities.)

Using code similar to the following changes *both* of these, but since I want the two to have different lettercase, it is not very helpful.

```
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\lowercase{Contents}}
```

Using `tocloft` would ruin the rest of my contents, as I'm using `titletoc` instead.

Using `Letters=UppercaseSmallCaps` in the heading isn't supported by my small caps font.

If there is a LaTeX non-parametric command that converts text to all caps or all lowercase, my problem would be solved.

Patching the `\tableofcontents` macro so that it doesn't print a title at all would be an optimal solution. Preventing `\tableofcontents` from altering the running headers would also be a solution. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find the code for the macro.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

% Set running headers to use small capitals.
% In my own document, I am actually selecting a different font. 
\newcommand{\headfont}{\scshape}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[CE]{\headfont\lowercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[CO]{\headfont\lowercase{\rightmark}}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Heading}
\section{Lorem}
\section{Ipsum}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Addendum: @Johannes_B gave a solution that fixes my particular problem very nicely. However, the general case of using entirely different pieces of text would also be worth addressing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am really not sure, if i understoof the question correctly.

In the following example, we simply patch the original definition of the `tableofcontents` to set the chapter title in ALL CAPS and the header in lower case.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

% Set running headers to use small capitals.
% In my own document, I am actually selecting a different font. 
\newcommand{\headfont}{\scshape}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[CE]{\headfont\lowercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[CO]{\headfont\lowercase{\rightmark}}

\makeatletter
\tracingpatches
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{
    \chapter*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
   }{
    \chapter*{
        \MakeUppercase{\contentsname}
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeLowercase\contentsname}{\MakeLowercase\contentsname}}%
   }{}{}
        \makeatother



\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Heading}
\section{Lorem}
\section{Ipsum}

\end{document}}
```

Comment: This solves the problem exactly! How would I go about finding the code for the original command (perhaps so I could tweak it further)?

Comment: The original code can be found in the class file `book.cls`. Depending on how big your changes are, i would recommend to 1) write your own class based on `book`, i.e. hiding the redefinitions; 2) instead of patching, a complete redefinition might be useful at times.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be using `\lowercase`, but rather the `fancyhdr` provided command `\nouppercase`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

% Set running headers to use small capitals.
% In my own document, I am actually selecting a different font. 
\newcommand{\headfont}{\scshape}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[CE]{\headfont\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[CO]{\headfont\nouppercase{\rightmark}}

% This is necessary if you're using babel
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \edef\contentsname{\noexpand\MakeUppercase{\unexpanded\expandafter{\contentsname}}}%
}
% Otherwise uncomment the following one
% \renewcommand\contentsname{CONTENTS}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Heading}
\section{Lorem}

\clearpage
\section{Ipsum}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, i forgot about `nouppercase`.